# SQL many joins grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, group-concat

I have three tables:

```
product:
    id
    name

product_image:
    product_id
    url

product_detail:
    product_id
    _key
    value
```

All I want to do is to fetch all the information about specific product in one query.
I am fetching group_concatenated images and details, but I have a problem with grouping (I think so). Sometimes I get doubled images. My query is:

```
   SELECT p.id, p.name,
GROUP_CONCAT(i.url ORDER BY i.id ASC SEPARATOR "{^sep^}") as imgs,
GROUP_CONCAT(d._key, "{^val^}", d.value ORDER BY d.id asc separator "{^sep^}") AS details
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_image i ON p.id = i.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_detail d ON p.id = d.product_id
WHERE p.id = ...
GROUP BY i.product_id, d.product_id 
ORDER BY p.id ASC LIMIT ...;
```

And, by the way, I am using "{^sep^}" as separator to later explode (in php) the result. I wanted to be sure, that url (and details) don't get exploded in a wrong way (for example if I used ',' as a separator and some url also contained ','). Is this a good approach?

Comment: By any chance are your duplicates occurring when the product_ID has multiple _key's? with multiple values?

Comment: Change those into: `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT i.url ...`

Comment: It's strange but my duplicates appeared in just one product with no details. I think the DISTINCT keyword made it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should group by p.id and p.name. You can also use DISTINCT:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name,
GROUP_CONCAT(i.url ORDER BY i.id ASC SEPARATOR "{^sep^}") as imgs,
GROUP_CONCAT(d._key, "{^val^}", d.value ORDER BY d.id asc separator "{^sep^}") AS details
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_image i ON p.id = i.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_detail d ON p.id = d.product_id
WHERE p.id = ...
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
ORDER BY p.id ASC LIMIT ...;
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.name,
GROUP_CONCAT(i.url ORDER BY i.id ASC SEPARATOR "{^sep^}") as imgs,
GROUP_CONCAT(d._key, "{^val^}", d.value ORDER BY d.id asc separator "{^sep^}") AS details
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_image i ON p.id = i.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_detail d ON p.id = d.product_id
WHERE p.id = ...
GROUP BY i.product_id, d.product_id 
ORDER BY p.id ASC LIMIT ...;
```